# AJAX PHP and Sessions Strange behaviour

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

I've read quite a few solutions on the web, but none really works for me. So Coming back to Stackoverflow:

The Issue is as following: My session gets created, it get's passed trough the pages, and it is usually still running if uploading a picture or changing information via AJAX. But sometimes, and that's not something I can reproduce - It just changes the Session ID as soon a picture is uploaded - I just get a new Session ID on the upload script - meaning if i browse trough the page it's the old ID but the picture of course won't get saved as it's a new session_id - and what's even more funny this one will stay the same for picture uploads until it's destroyed! So in fact I'll have 2 session_id's for the same session.

I am getting unpatient so it would be really nice if somebody had a clue for me. Of course session_start is executed at the top of every page ;).

Comment: please show code you have tried

Comment: I've encountered this madness a few times, it's usually attributable to users behind strange load balancers or wonky ISP squid / similar caches. Does just using a cookie clear it up? We really do need to see code to rule out something simple you might be overlooking, but I suspect you're hitting what I described.

Comment: I've added the bit of code I think is necessary for this problem, thank you for commenting.

Comment: No changing it to the usage of cookies doesn't change a thing :(

Answer (score 0):

I am doing quite a few unneccesary mistakes since a couple of weeks.. Oh well of course there was nothing wrong with the code as it was... The mistake was on my side as of I forget that flash doesn't pass anything if not told to.

And as I use the swfuploader libary, oh well I think you can imagine the rest.

Don't ever forget to pass your session id if using flash!